# Как разделить выпадающее меню на несколько колонок?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать так чтобы колонка выпадающего меню поделилась на несколько колонок если список категорий очень длинный. Подскажите как это сделать

Comment: Можно проверять количество элементов, при нужном количествe манипулировать свойством column-count

Comment: column-count глючит в андроиде-хроме и фф, не совету.
Можно на js считать, если кол-во больше чем Н, то разбивать на разные блоки.

Comment: Использовал многократно, никаких глюков не наблюдалось

Comment: @Vearo [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=column-count)

Answer (score 0):

Задайте для родительского блока свойство `max-height`, ограничивающее его максимальную высоту, и используйте CSS-колонки. Подробнее, как их использовать: https://html5book.ru/css3-columns/